# Click on a link cause application restart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two similar link in my registration page. one works and the other cause application restart. Both are exactly the same

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="top:15px">
    Already have an account? @Html.ActionLink(linkText: "Sign In", actionName: "Login", controllerName: "Account")
</div>

<div class="alert alert-info">
    <strong>Want to be an affiliate?  @Html.ActionLink(linkText: "Join", actionName: "RegisterAffiliate", controllerName: "Account") our affiliation program!</strong>
</div>
```

in html source I see

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="top:15px">
    Already have an account? <a href="/Account/Login">Sign In</a>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-info">
    <strong>Want to be an affiliate?  <a href="/Account/RegisterAffiliate">Join</a> our affiliation program!</strong>
</div>
```

The first link works normally but when I click on the second one, it cause application restart. I mean it takes me to `Application_Start()` in `Global.asax`

Both links are in the same `form` tag

Below are the controllers:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult RegisterAffiliate()
{
    RegisterAffiliateViewModel model = new RegisterAffiliateViewModel();
    using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        model.Countries = db.Countries.ToList();
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

When I click on the second link, it even doesn't go to the controller, because it doesn't hit my break-point.

I've been digging into this issue for few days. Please help.

Comment: Do you have a `View` titled "RegisterAffiliate"?  Because that's what you're returning in your second method.

Comment: What do you mean by "application restart"? Do you have any special routing?

Comment: Sounds like your `Login` action is working correctly. To test things out, add a temp action, let's say `RegisterAffiliate2` or some other name, create the `view` and `model` for it, and return some test/dummy data to see if things flow normally. Maybe this'll help you hone in on the problem area.

Comment: @Tim, I have a view named RegisterAffiliate

Comment: @DavidG, I have mentioned that Application_Restart() gets called

Comment: @ArashMotamedi, I cope/pasted the RegisterAffiliate and named it RegisterAffiliate2 and it works correctly!!

Comment: My only suggestion is to check spelling everywhere. Affiliate is a terrible word to spell!

Comment: That's weird. now I have RegisterAffiliate and RegisterAffilate2 views, they are exactly the same. I , have controllers as well, exactly the same with different names (RegisterAffiliate and RegisterAffilate2), the second one works!!

Comment: There is not typo or spelling issue

Comment: Note that you spelled affiliate differently in that last comment. Are you sure you got it right in the app?

Comment: that's a typo in comment, code is correct. thanks for mentionning

Comment: Delete your original and rename RA2 to RA. Hopefully your weird bug is gone, even if we didn't find it.

Comment: Looks like the RA, conflicts with something else. I searched my entire solution and could not find anything. I'm gonna get rid of that evil name :) and hope it won't happen again. Thank you all